# PhoneGap- Contacts are not showing

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to show the contacts lists from the device using PhoneGap development. But its not displaying the contacts.

Neither its showing any kind of errors.

Please any one help me to find out what is wrong in the below code as i am begginer in phonegap.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Contacts Demo </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function init()
    {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        var options=new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter="";
        var fields=["name","phoneNumbers"];
        navigator.service.contacts.find(fields,onSuccess,onError,options);
    }

    function onSuccess(contacts)
    {
        var ulr=document.getElementById("list");
        for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++)
        {
            var name=contacts[i].name.formatted;
            var phoneNumber=contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value;
            var li=document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = "<a href=\"tel://"+phoneNumber+"\">"+name+"</a>";
            ulr=appendChild(li);
        }
    };

    function onError()
    {
        alert('onError!');
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Contacts List</h1>
<ul id="list"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**Logcat:**

```
04-02 16:05:37.167: I/PhoneGapLog(7141): phonegap.xml missing. Ignoring...
04-02 16:05:37.167: I/System.out(7141): loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/contactindex.html)
04-02 16:05:37.167: I/System.out(7141): url=file:///android_asset/www/contactindex.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
04-02 16:05:37.377: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): We are in our onMeasure method
04-02 16:05:37.377: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): Old Height = 0
04-02 16:05:37.377: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): Height = 762
04-02 16:05:37.377: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): Old Width = 0
04-02 16:05:37.377: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): Width = 480
04-02 16:05:37.377: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): Ignore this event
04-02 16:05:37.477: D/gralloc_goldfish(7141): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-02 16:05:37.657: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): We are in our onMeasure method
04-02 16:05:37.657: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): Old Height = 762
04-02 16:05:37.657: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): Height = 762
04-02 16:05:37.667: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): Old Width = 480
04-02 16:05:37.667: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): Width = 480
04-02 16:05:37.667: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7141): Ignore this event
04-02 16:05:38.698: E/SQLiteLog(7141): (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
04-02 16:05:38.698: E/SQLiteLog(7141): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
04-02 16:05:38.707: D/WebKit(7141): ERROR: 
04-02 16:05:38.707: D/WebKit(7141): SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
04-02 16:05:38.707: D/WebKit(7141): Cause - unable to open database file
04-02 16:05:38.707: D/WebKit(7141): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
04-02 16:05:38.907: D/PhoneGapLog(7141): null: Line 1 : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:36419/01c9cf14-1235-4458-9b68-33a094aad126. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
04-02 16:05:38.917: E/Web Console(7141): XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:36419/01c9cf14-1235-4458-9b68-33a094aad126. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. at null:1
04-02 16:05:38.987: D/PhoneGapLog(7141): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.1.0.js: Line 930 : JSCallback Error: Request failed.
04-02 16:05:38.997: I/Web Console(7141): JSCallback Error: Request failed. at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.1.0.js:930
04-02 16:05:39.218: D/PhoneGapLog(7141): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.1.0.js: Line 769 : Error in success callback: Network Status1 = TypeError: Cannot read property 'contacts' of undefined
04-02 16:05:39.218: I/Web Console(7141): Error in success callback: Network Status1 = TypeError: Cannot read property 'contacts' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.1.0.js:769
04-02 16:05:39.347: D/dalvikvm(7141): GC_CONCURRENT freed 210K, 4% free 8192K/8455K, paused 18ms+5ms, total 58ms
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have never coded with phonegap, but, looking at your logcat, it is saying that you need to open database. Not sure, if this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add READ_CONTACTS permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

I recommend you to delete funciton `init()` and just let:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
```

Cause init() is not triggered.

If you do all the Phongap steps and you didn't get errors you must try 1 last think that works in the past for me just save you'r project data and do `phonegap build` or `phonegap build app_platform`.

Comment: I'm looking it but this aren't the logs you are looking for try to find `webConsole` logs.

Comment: Oks I see a few below and the `webConsole` log says: "Cannot read property 'contacts' of undefined" you have javascript errors to accessing contats information.

Comment: Just last try, Did you install contacts plugin?

Comment: Take a last look to my answer hope that will be the solution

Answer (score 0):

check out if u'r phoneNumbers array is not null